# Safari Push Notificatin + permission "denied" and no log found

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, push-notification

I am try to integrate safari push notification. I referred following link.
http://samuli.hakoniemi.net/how-to-implement-safari-push-notifications-on-your-website/#resources

My client file is at...
-public_html/push/index.html

Server configuration files are at...
-public_html/push/node_modules/express/index.js

Push packages and log file are at...
-public_html/push/v1/pushPackages/[my push id]/myPackage.zip
-public_html/push/v1/pushPackages/[my push id]/log      (file)

My index.js file has following code.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = require('./lib/express');

//Test code for Safari push notification
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


app.listen(port);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

app.post('/v1/pushPackages/[my push id]', function(req, res) {
alert('hello');
    res.sendfile('myPushPackage.zip');
});

app.post('/v1/log', function(req, res) {
});
```

My client file (index.html) has following code :

```
!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Safari Push Notifications</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Safari Push Notifications</h1>
        <a href="#" id="subscribe">Subscribe</a>
        <script>


var pushId = [my push id];
document.body.onload = function() {
    // Ensure that the user can receive Safari Push Notifications.
    if ('safari' in window && 'pushNotification' in window.safari) {
        var permissionData = window.safari.pushNotification.permission(pushId);
        checkRemotePermission(permissionData);

    } else {
        alert("Push notifications not supported.");
    }
};

var checkRemotePermission = function (permissionData) {

    if (permissionData.permission === 'default') {
     alert("default.");
        // This is a new web service URL and its validity is unknown.
        console.log("The user is making a decision");
//alert('The user is making a decision');
        var userinfo={};
  window.safari.pushNotification.requestPermission(
            'https://[mydomain]/push', // The web service URL.
            pushId,     // The Website Push ID.
            userinfo, // Data that you choose to send to your server to help you identify the user.
            checkRemotePermission         // The callback function.
        );
    }
    else if (permissionData.permission === 'denied') {
     alert("denied.");
        // The user said no.
        console.log('denied');
    }
    else if (permissionData.permission === 'granted') {
     alert("granted.");
        // The web service URL is a valid push provider, and the user said yes.
        // permissionData.deviceToken is now available to use.
        console.log("The user said yes, with token: "+ permissionData.deviceToken);
    }
};
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It give us the alert of "default" then after "denied" alert.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/v1/pushPackages/[pushid]', function(req, res) {  
    console.log('Serving File');    
    res.sendFile('aa.zip', { root: __dirname });
});

app.post('/v1/log', function(req, res) {  
         console.log('Received LOG');
         console.log(req.body);
});
```

This Solved my problem having tha aa.zip file on same location of index.js file. For more check your node log as console.log(req.body) show the error.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not longer so; my code at: https://pizzomarinellafs.inarrivo.net/testSafari/ always return denied.
Neither of those call-backs are ever called:
app.post('https://websockets.inarrivo.net/v2/pushPackages/web.net.inarrivo.pizzomarinellafs', function(req, res) { 
 console.log('register');  
    res.sendfile('pushPackage.zip');  
}); 

app.post('/v1/pushPackages/web.net.inarrivo.pizzomarinellafs', function(req, res) {  
    console.log('Registering: Serving File');    
    res.sendFile('pushPackage.zip', { root: __dirname });
});